# add a section/tab on the right section of all categories in front end magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, xml, uicomponent, magento-2.2.5

Hi there I want to add my custom section/tab on the right section of all the categories for getting a clear idea I am attaching this image 
[image: Snap of frontend]

This is the men section I want to add the same custom tab on all of the sections!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add custom section/tab through custom theme:**

add below code in catalog_category_view.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.tab" template="Magento_Catalog::customtab.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

create customtab.phtml file and add your custom code.

**add custom section/tab through module:**

override catalog_category_view.xml and add below code

```
 <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.tab" template="vendor_module::customtab.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

create customtab.phtml file and add your custom code.

Comment: Hi Kinjal It works but it shifts the whole section to the right side of the page any idea about it??

Comment: Solved it too Thanks for the answer I am accepting your answer Thanks